# Using findByIdAndUpdate functionality inserts duplicate data in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a data inside the MongoDB database . I am using `findByIdAndUpdate` function to do this , but a duplicate data gets inserted into the database . This is happening every time I am trying to update the data . Also used `db.collection.update()` but the same thing is happening .
I have also used

```
findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $set: {isPrime:true} },function(err,data)
```

It is also not working .

Code :

```
router.get('/getPremium',function(req,res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    var userId = req.user.id  ;
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(req.user._id);
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,{isPrime:true},function(err,data){
      if(err) throw err;
    })
    res.redirect('/');
  }else{
   res.redirect('/');
  }
})
```

I have also found answer to this [findOneAndUpdate causing duplication problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103351/findoneandupdate-causing-duplication-problem) but did not found it useful .

Any help regarding this will be helpful for me .

Comment: `findByIdAndUpdate` just updates an existing doc, so I'm not clear on what's duplicated.

Comment: But when I am trying to update , it inserts a new data with the updated values . And this happens every time I update the value .

Comment: Hmm...sounds like we'll need a [mcve].